# Doris on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-doris

I encountered a connection timeout error when using the Doris on Elasticsearch external table. The detailed information is as follows. What could be the reason?

> Error Failed to execute sql: java.sql.SQLException: (conn=212930) errCode = 2, detailMessage = (xxx.xxx)[INTERNAL_ERROR]Failed to connect to ES server, errmsg is: [INTERNAL_ERROR]Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx port 9200 : Connection timed out

what can i do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have already resolved this issue, and the solution is to add an additional parameter：

```
"nodes_discovery" = "false".
```

Just in case someone else may encounters the same problem, and I'm using Alibaba Cloud's Elasticsearch.